# Как отправить сообщение через бота в тред на C#

Tags: c#

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Создание экземпляра клиента для работы с API бота
        var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");

        var chatID = id;
        var threadID = id;
        // Отправка сообщения в чат
        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync($"{chatID}", "Игры обновлены, перезагрузите все свободные пк");
    }
```

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема

Comment: я не знал куда ставить id треда

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    // Создание экземпляра клиента для работы с API бота
    var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");

    var chatID = id чата;
    var threadID = id тапки;
    // Отправка сообщения в чат
    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync($"{chatID}", "Игры обновлены, перезагрузите все свободные пк" threadID);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]